# Thread ID assignment

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a basic question about thread IDs. 
After start of my application the UI-Thread has the thread ID=1;
I started a new task which has the thread-ID=3.

Thus, my question is:

How is the assignment of thread-ids arranged?

Before I thought the Computer will count the thread-IDs gradually.

Comment: Don't forget that the garbage collector runs on its own thread. In the end though, I don't know why it would matter how they're assigned so long as you can ascertain a thread's ID.

Comment: Why are you asking? Is it just curiosity or you are trying to solve some problem?

Comment: No, just out of understanding. I have to describe my thread managing in a paper.

Comment: @TimDor If your thread management relies on how the thread IDs are generated then there is a major problem with your algorithm.  It should be written such that it works *regardless* of how IDs are assigned to threads, so long as each thread has a unique ID and that it doesn't change over the lifetime of the thread.

Comment: @Servy it works fine. I created a data sequence UML-diagram. I wanted to describe the Threads assignment. That means, which data are processed in which thread. But it is nothing of importance.

Comment: @TimDor If your algorithm works fine regardless of how the IDs are generated, then why would you be writing out the specifics of how the IDs are generated, given that your solution works *regardless* of how they're generated?

Comment: Consider thread id's random, even if today on your machine there seems to be an underlying consecutive pattern. The only thing useful about a thread id, is that as long as your thread is active no other active thread in your process(or appdomain?) has that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tasks are orchestrated by a task scheduler that handles the low-level work of queuing tasks onto threads.

The default task scheduler is based on the .NET Framework 4 thread pool, which enables you to use threads more efficiently by 
providing your application with a pool of worker threads that are managed by the system.

The default size of the thread pool for a process depends on several factors and the thread pool uses its own algorithm for allocating the threads.

Thread ID's are unique per process during a thread's lifecycle. After a thread terminates, its ID can be reused by the thread pool.